# Why can't I use '0x80000000' to initialize an array of int?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, int, list-initialization

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int arr[1] = {0x80000000};
    std::cout<<arr[0]<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The above code will get the following error:

> error: narrowing conversion of ‘2147483648u’ from ‘unsigned int’ to
>   ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]   int arr[1] = {0x80000000};

But the following code works perfectly:

```
#include<iostream>    
int main()
{
    int arr[1];
    arr[0] = 0x80000000;
    std::cout<<arr[0]<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is: Why can't I use '0x80000000' to initialize an array of `int`?

Comment: You can, just not of a 32-but type (which `int` seems to be on your machine).

Comment: `[1]` is a red herring, you would get the same behaviour with plain `int`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0x80000000` can't fit `int` here, so it's an [integer literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal) with type `unsigned int`. For initialization, implicit conversion is needed, but other than assignment, implicit conversions are limited, i.e. narrowing conversions are prohibited in [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions) (since C++11):

> list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions by prohibiting the following:
>
> - ...
> - conversion from integer or unscoped enumeration type to integer type that cannot represent all values of the original, except where source is a constant expression whose value can be stored exactly in the target type

And about the behavior of the implicit conversion, i.e. [integral conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions) in the assignment:

> If the destination type is signed, the value does not change if the source integer can be represented in the destination type. Otherwise the result is implementation-defined.

The behavior of out of range conversion is implementation-defined, e.g. it may wrap around according to the rules of the representation (typically 2's complement).

Comment: Re. the last paragraph: this is called out-of-range conversion, not *overflow* (which is what happens when an arithmetic operation would produce a result out of range)

Answer (score 2):

It does not "work perfectly". It may *compile* when you use a construct that silently allows truncation, but that doesn't mean that no truncation happens. You'll still get the wrong result since your value doesn't fit in a `signed int`, the compiler just doesn't help you spot your bug in that case.

Remember; "compiles" != "works".

Answer (score 1):

because here `arr[0] = 0x80000000;` the compiler performs a cast (we're talking int=32 bits here), which is implementation-defined (depending on the compiler). You may get warnings on some compilers too.

But the compiler cannot perform a cast when initializing because it maps directly the array to the memory.

Comment: Just to nitpick. The compiler performs *conversions*, some implicit, and some explicit. The programmer specifies such an explicit conversion by *casting*.

Comment: You didn't mention the important point that this *conversion* (not cast) does not happen since C++11, the code is ill-formed. However it is nothing to do with "maps directly the array to the memory" (whatever that is supposed to mean). This code was legal in C++03 (with implementation-defined behaviour as you explain). The change in C++11 was done with the aim of helping programmers avoid writing bugs, not for any technical limitations.